# How to send multipule attachments in the email in Spring?

Tags: spring

I have some code to send attachment with email but I'd like to send multiple attachments. Here's my current code:

```java
MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
try{
  MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
  helper.setFrom(fromEmailId);
  helper.setTo(emailId);
  helper.setSubject(emailSubject);
  String userName = "";

  helper.setText("HI", true);

  File file = new File(System.getenv("CATALINA_HOME") + File.separator + attachmentFolder + File.separator + fileName);


  String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
  FileSystemResource fileSystemResource = new FileSystemResource(filePath.trim());
  helper.addAttachment(fileSystemResource.getFilename(), fileSystemResource);
  message.send();
```

Comment: Create a zip and send as attachment is good solution for sending multiple files ..

Comment: Just curious, did you thy adding another attachment to the helper? helper.addAttachment(fileSystemResource.getFilename()fileSystemResource);                                                                    helper.addAttachment(anotherFileSystemResource.getFilename(),
                anotherFileSystemResource);

Comment: Call `addAttachment` again, and again and again and... Well you probably get the drift :).

Answer (score 4):

The below code is worked for me .

```
   MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
try{
   MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
  helper.setFrom(fromEmailId);
   helper.setTo(emailId);
   helper.setSubject(emailSubject);
   String userName = "";

  helper.setText("HI", true);

    File file = new File(System.getenv("CATALINA_HOME") + File.separator +        attachmentFolder + File.separator + fileName);


  String filePath1 = file.getAbsolutePath();
  FileSystemResource fileSystemResource1 = new      FileSystemResource1(filePath1.trim());
   helper.addAttachment(fileSystemResource1.getFilename(), fileSystemResource1);

   String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
  FileSystemResource fileSystemResource = new  FileSystemResource(filePath.trim());
     helper.addAttachment(fileSystemResource.getFilename(), fileSystemResource);

  message.send();
```